# Pandas printing column of order when export to excel

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe, export-to-excel

I exported some data from Python/pandas to Excel, and it includes a column that represents the order. Example:

```
+----+---------+------------------+------+------+---------+
|    | Name    | Task             | Team | Date | Month   |
+----+---------+------------------+------+------+---------+
| 0  | John    | Market study     | A    | 1    | Month 1 |
+----+---------+------------------+------+------+---------+
| 1  | Michael | Customer service | B    | 1    | Month 1 |
+----+---------+------------------+------+------+---------+
| 2  | Joanna  | Accounting       | C    | 1    | Month 1 |
+----+---------+------------------+------+------+---------+
| 3  | John    | Accounting       | B    | 2    | Month 1 |
+----+---------+------------------+------+------+---------+
| 4  | Michael | Customer service | A    | 2    | Month 1 |
+----+---------+------------------+------+------+---------+
| 5  | Joanna  | Market study     | C    | 2    | Month 1 |
+----+---------+------------------+------+------+---------+
| 6  | John    | Market study     | A    | 1    | Month 3 |
+----+---------+------------------+------+------+---------+
| 7  | Michael | Customer service | B    | 1    | Month 3 |
+----+---------+------------------+------+------+---------+
| 8  | Joanna  | Accounting       | C    | 1    | Month 3 |
+----+---------+------------------+------+------+---------+
| 9  | John    | Customer service | A    | 2    | Month 3 |
+----+---------+------------------+------+------+---------+
| 10 | Michael | Accounting       | B    | 2    | Month 3 |
+----+---------+------------------+------+------+---------+
```

The problem is that when I import the file back into pandas, for my computer, the column on the far left that represents order is not taken into account; whereas for other people, it is. Why, and what's the solution?

Comment: Can you please clarify your statement a bit? Does your excel file have the index column (far left column) and when you import it using `pandas` it goes away?

Comment: Hi, my code does not have column of index. However when I export to excel it does. When I import that same excel file, for some people it load the index column as a column in the dataframe; however for my computer it does not.

Comment: When you export to excel set index=False.  `df.to_excel(index=False)`

Comment: *"I exported some code to excel (format)"* Err, no. You exported some *data* to Excel. And you didn't tell us where you exported it from, I thought you mean some spreadsheet package, but you meant "exported from pandas". We can't know from where you exported it. You have to state your issue.

Comment: The *"column on the far left that represents order"* is called the **index**. So your issue is either *"when I export data (from pandas) to Excel, the index is dropped"* or else *"when I read the Excel file into pandas, the index is dropped"*.

Comment: yes, seems like a bad question, sorry about that

Comment: FARRAF, I never said it was a bad question, I get that you're new, I'm trying to welcome you to SO and help you learn the terminology to ask questions so you get good results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `df.to_excel(file.xlsx, index=False)` to save to file.xlsx without the index